# Consolidate data from different excel worksheets basis column header

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a excel dashboard from around 42 different excel worksheets. I am trying to consolidate all the worksheets in to a single master data sheet. The 42 different worksheets may have same number of headers as another worksheets or more headers. Can someone help me with the VBA code where I can match column headers and if it matches then append the column else create a new column at the last and paste data over there.

I have consolidated all the worksheets into one worksheet but it is not in the expected format.

```
Function fn_LastRow(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop
    fn_LastRow = lRow
End Function


Function fn_LastColumn(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    lCol = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Columns(lCol)) = 0 And lCol <> 1
        lCol = lCol - 1
    Loop
    fn_LastColumn = lCol
End Function


Sub Consolidate_Data()
    On Error GoTo IfError

    Dim Sht As Worksheet, DstSht As Worksheet
    Dim LstRow As Long, LstCol As Long, DstRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer, EnRange As String
    Dim SrcRng As Range
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate_Data").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set DstSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        DstSht.Name = "Consolidate_Data"
    End With
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name <> DstSht.Name Then
           DstRow = fn_LastRow(DstSht) + 1
           LstRow = fn_LastRow(Sht)
           LstCol = fn_LastColumn(Sht)
           EnRange = Sht.Cells(LstRow, LstCol).Address
           Set SrcRng = Sht.Range("A1:" & EnRange)
            If DstRow + SrcRng.Rows.Count > DstSht.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows to place the data in the Consolidate_Data worksheet."
                GoTo IfError
            End If
            SrcRng.Copy Destination:=DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow)
        End If
    Next

IfError:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

For eg.

Input:

> ```
> Brand   1_day_growth    1_week_growth   1_month_growth
> ABC     10      12      18
> ACD     12      18      16
>
> Brand   1_week_growth   2_week_growth    1_month_growth  6_month_growth
> BCD     10      12      14      16
> BDE     12      14      16      13
>
> Brand   1_yr_growth
> CDE     9
> ```

Output I am getting:

> ```
> Brand   1_day_growth    1_week_growth    1_month_growth
> ABC     10      12      18
> ACD     12      18      16
> Brand   1_week_growth   2_week_growth    1_month_growth     6_month_growth
> BCD     10      12      14      16
> BDE     12      14      16      13
> Brand   1_yr_growth
> CDE     9
> ```

Expected Output:

> ```
> Brand   1_day_growth    1_week_growth   1_month_growth  2_week_growth   6_week_growth   1_yr_growth
> ABC     10      12      18
> ACD     12      18      16
> BCD     -       10      14      12      16
> BDE     -       12      16      14      13
> CDE     -       -       -       -       -       9
> ```

Comment: Wrap `Set SrcRng = Sht.Range("A1:" & EnRange)` around an `IF` condition. If its the first sheet then: `Set SrcRng = Sht.Range("A1:" & EnRange)` else: `Set SrcRng = Sht.Range("A2:" & EnRange)`